# When I try to install ipython notebook-gtk2: error

Tags: system-installation, dpkg

When I try to install `ipython notebook-gtk2`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ipython_2.4.1-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix this ans install the mentioned package?

```
total 4
-rw-r----- 1 root root    0 Jul 20  2016 lock
drwx------ 2 _apt root 4096 Mar 27 21:48 partial
```

Comment: Run `sudo apt clean` and try again.

Comment: i do that and same answer.

Comment: Run `sudo apt clean && ls -l /var/cache/apt/archives` and [edit] your question with the output.

Comment: ls ----->  No such file or directory

Comment: You sure you wrote it correctly? Do you mind trying again, just copy/paste?

Comment: after copy i get this ----->                                                                                                         -rw-r----- 1 root root    0 Jul 20  2016 lock
drwx------ 2 _apt root 4096 Mar 27 19:38 partial

Comment: [Edit] your question with it

Comment: eh . how can i do that . type it with -gtk2?

Comment: Click on the highlighted word ->[edit]<- and add the information I asked you for. But, again, you should be able to install it just fine already.

Comment: when i type edit i get this ----> Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/%{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at /usr/bin/edit line 528.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. Are we talking about the same thing? I mean **this** ---->http://askubuntu.com/posts/897443/edit

Comment: yes . same thing . but i cant open editing dpkg . idont know what is wrong.

Comment: Just try again to install the package you wanted in the first place

Comment: no . it dosnt work . ok